# What's the foot retention used by pro track cyclists?

Tags: pedals, track-racing

I have recently started hitting my local velodrome in Herne Hill and it's great fun.
I notice the majority of experienced riders use road pedals such as Look or SPD-SL. The rental bikes just have toe-clips and straps but I, among others, bring along my own pedals which are SPD which work fine.

I noticed when watching the Olympics and other pro velodrome events that the riders appear to have straps on their pedals. What system are they using? Does it combine a road pedal with a strap for extra stiffness or is it a secret custom-made system?

Comment: https://www.velodromeshop.net/pedals Here is a discussion on the pedals+strap solution adopted for track cycling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as you suggest, a combination of a standard road cleat and straps as a 'belt and braces' approach.

A quick google showed some packages of both sold [together](http://www.velodromeshop.net/index.php?p=product&id=812)

Answer (score 1):

From experience, (being an amateur seeing pros at events) a lot of people use Speedplays for better pedal clearance. You can also do something slick like [this](http://prollyisnotprobably.com/2010/08/bill-thomsen-speedplay-toe-clip-adapter/) to create a clip/cleat combination.